# How do I set the password of an account in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

```
ENV USERNAME ros
RUN adduser --ingroup sudo --disabled-password --gecos "" --shell /bin/bash --home /home/$USERNAME $USERNAME
RUN bash -c 'echo $USERNAME:ros | chpasswd'
ENV HOME /home/$USERNAME
```

My goal is to have an account with sudo privileges.

The context is that I am trying to create a Docker image with a working installation of ROS. The ROS installation is complicated and includes running many commands and scripts. I know the above statement is probably wrong because it is creating files with owner `ros` and group `sudo`.

Comment: Could you add a little bit more of context? Why do you want that?

Comment: I could but I thought a small tight question is better. The context is that I am trying to create a docker image with a working installation of ROS. The ROS installation is complicated and includes running many commands and scripts. I know the above statement is probably wrong because it is creating files with owner ros and group sudo. Well I take that back. When sudo is enabled on an account does it appear in group `sudo`?

Comment: As I said in another answer, you almost never use passwords or sudo in Docker.  With your example `docker history` can retrieve the password in plain text.  You might consider using [Vagrant](https://vagrantup.com/) to build a virtual machine that acts more like a normal Linux environment; that seems more in line with what you're trying to build given the questions you're asking.

Comment: Yes I remember. But I really want to learn how to use Docker. And if I am calling a script that is part of an install that I didnt wrtite, and it does sudo, is there a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with the comments saying that in the majority of cases you avoid sudo in Docker, I also had the same situation where I needed to have a non-root user with passwordless sudo privileges inside Docker.

[This is my Dockerfile that defines a sudo user](https://github.com/DannyBen/docker-ubuntu/blob/master/Dockerfile)

This is the relevant part from it:

```
# Set a passwordless sudoer user
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" ubuntu && \
    usermod -aG sudo ubuntu && \
    echo "%sudo  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/nopasswd

# Start the container as the user
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu
USER ubuntu
CMD bash
```

Hope this helps.